# How to correctly configure an advanced route in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I'm new to angular. I have a project creation page that contains form steps.
The first steps creates the project then in the other steps I just update the related info of each step. as I imagine the route for this should be something like :

```
project/form              // for creating new project
project/form/:id          // for updating a project
project/form/:id/step2    // for updating second step
projectform/:id/step3     // .........
```

All of the previous routes share the same main component. My components looks like the following, the main component is loaded in the routerOutlet and inside it there are steps components :

[image]

The route of this :

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/project/form', name: 'Project_Form', component: ProjectFormComponent, useAsDefault: false},
    //new AuxRoute({path: '/:id', component: ProjectFormComponent}),
])
```

Can I specify which step I should show from the route or I must set step name as a parameter the switch between them in main component. any advises for this situation, am I doing it correctly or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass step as additional parameter.

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/project/form', name: 'Project_Form', component: ProjectFormComponent, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/project/form/:id', name: 'Project_Form', component: ProjectFormComponent},
    {path: '/project/form/:id/:step', name: 'Project_Form', component: ProjectFormComponent},
])
```

Your `ProjectFormComponent` should look like this

```
import {RouteParams} from "angular2/router";

@Component({
   ...
   template: `
   <step-1 *ngIf='step == 1'></step-1>
   <step-2 *ngIf='step == 2'></step-2>
   <step-2 *ngIf='step == 2'></step-2>
   `
})
export class ProjectFormComponent {

    constructor(params: RouteParams, public step){
       if(params.get('id'){
           if(params.get('step')){ 
              this.step = parseInt(params.get('step'))
              editProject(params.get('id'), this.step)
           } else() { 
              this.step = 1 
              editProject(params.get('id'), 1)
           } 
       } else {
           this.step = 1
           createNewProject()
       }
    }
    createNewProject(){
       ...
    }
    editProject(id, step) { 
       ... 
    }
}
```

`step` is available in the template to selectively display the required part